# ERROR: Out of global stack

Tags: prolog

I'm trying to create a predicate that will output all the lists minus one element each time. For a list [a, b, c], I want predicate return

```
a, [b, c]
b, [a, c]
c, [a, b]
```

I've created the follow predicate:

```
elem_list(Elems, X, ElemsNoX) :-
    append(ElemsA, [X], ElemsAX),
    append(ElemsAX, ElemsB, Elems),
    append(ElemsA, ElemsB, ElemsNoX).
```

Which seems to work, but when trying to execute it I'm getting the following error:

```
?- elem_list([a,b,c], X, L).
X = a,
L = [b, c] ;
X = b,
L = [a, c] ;
X = c,
L = [a, b] ;
ERROR: Out of global stack
```

What does this error mean? and how can I resolve it?

Comment: It means that you get into infinite recursion.

Comment: @WillemVanOnsem but I didn't use recursion

Comment: that's not necessary, `append/3` is build recursively.

Comment: The problem is that your `append/3` calls have an infinite number of possible solutions for Prolog to try in order to see if it solves your problem. If you're allowed to use predefined predicates, why not just use `select/3`? `elem_list(List, X, NoX) :- select(X, List, NoX).`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In most Prolog version, you can use `trace.` to enable a mode where each step the Prolog interpreter takes is printed. When turning on `trace.` for your predicate, it reveals:

```
[trace]  ?- elem_list([a,b,c], X, L).
   Call: (7) elem_list([a, b, c], _G25166352, _G25166353) ? creep
   Call: (8) lists:append(_G25166456, [_G25166352], _G25166458) ? creep
   Exit: (8) lists:append([], [_G25166352], [_G25166352]) ? creep
   Call: (8) lists:append([_G25166352], _G25166457, [a, b, c]) ? creep
   Exit: (8) lists:append([a], [b, c], [a, b, c]) ? creep
   Call: (8) lists:append([], [b, c], _G25166353) ? creep
   Exit: (8) lists:append([], [b, c], [b, c]) ? creep
   Exit: (7) elem_list([a, b, c], a, [b, c]) ? creep
X = a,
L = [b, c] ;
   Redo: (8) lists:append(_G25166456, [_G25166352], _G25166458) ? creep
   Exit: (8) lists:append([_G25166449], [_G25166352], [_G25166449, _G25166352]) ? creep
   Call: (8) lists:append([_G25166449, _G25166352], _G25166463, [a, b, c]) ? creep
   Exit: (8) lists:append([a, b], [c], [a, b, c]) ? creep
   Call: (8) lists:append([a], [c], _G25166353) ? creep
   Exit: (8) lists:append([a], [c], [a, c]) ? creep
   Exit: (7) elem_list([a, b, c], b, [a, c]) ? creep
X = b,
L = [a, c] ;
   Redo: (8) lists:append([_G25166449|_G25166450], [_G25166352], [_G25166449|_G25166453]) ? creep
   Exit: (8) lists:append([_G25166449, _G25166455], [_G25166352], [_G25166449, _G25166455, _G25166352]) ? creep
   Call: (8) lists:append([_G25166449, _G25166455, _G25166352], _G25166469, [a, b, c]) ? creep
   Exit: (8) lists:append([a, b, c], [], [a, b, c]) ? creep
   Call: (8) lists:append([a, b], [], _G25166353) ? creep
   Exit: (8) lists:append([a, b], [], [a, b]) ? creep
   Exit: (7) elem_list([a, b, c], c, [a, b]) ? creep
X = c,
L = [a, b] ;
   Redo: (8) lists:append([_G25166449, _G25166455|_G25166456], [_G25166352], [_G25166449, _G25166455|_G25166459]) ? creep
   Exit: (8) lists:append([_G25166449, _G25166455, _G25166461], [_G25166352], [_G25166449, _G25166455, _G25166461, _G25166352]) ? creep
   Call: (8) lists:append([_G25166449, _G25166455, _G25166461, _G25166352], _G25166475, [a, b, c]) ? creep
   Fail: (8) lists:append([_G25166449, _G25166455, _G25166461, _G25166352], _G25166475, [a, b, c]) ? creep
```

So we see that the *first* `append/3` call (note the `[_G25166352]` as second argument). simply generates new variables. We can confirm this by perform an isolated call:

```
?- append(ElemsA, [X], ElemsAX).
ElemsA = [],
ElemsAX = [X] ;
ElemsA = [_G25167627],
ElemsAX = [_G25167627, X] ;
ElemsA = [_G25167627, _G25167633],
ElemsAX = [_G25167627, _G25167633, X] ;
ElemsA = [_G25167627, _G25167633, _G25167639],
ElemsAX = [_G25167627, _G25167633, _G25167639, X]
```

So what happens is that with append, a list with **ungrounded variables** on both the left and the right. Of course these lists have no chance of being grounded completely: these lists contain more elements than the initial list `[a,b,c]` so that means these will eventually fail later in the process (we can see that as we further trace the program). But evidently the first predicate does not know that, and thus simply keeps constructing lists until it runs out of memory.

The above stated solution is thus not a good way to do this.

We can for instance write a custom predicate that succeeds:

```
exclude([],_,[]).
exclude([H|T],H,T).
exclude([H|T],X,[H|T2]) :-
    exclude(T,X,T2).
```

The code works as follows: if the first parameter unifies with `[]` (the empty list), we return the empty list and leave the part to be excluded unground. In case the first parameter unifies with `[H|T]` (a list with a head `H` and a tail `T`), there are two options: we pick the head `H` as element to exclude, and thus return the tail `T`, or we postpone excluding, and let the recursive call pick an element.

The above stated program will allow us to exclude *no* element:

```
?- exclude([a,b,c], X, L).
X = a,
L = [b, c] ;
X = b,
L = [a, c] ;
X = c,
L = [a, b] ;
L = [a, b, c].
```

So the last line simply leaves `X` ungrounded, and returns the entire list `[a,b,c]`.

If you do not want that, you can simply remove the first line:

```
exclude1([H|T],H,T).
exclude1([H|T],X,[H|T2]) :-
    exclude1(T,X,T2).
```

Now Prolog is forced to make at least one element of the first list the element to exclude. This then will produce:

```
?- exclude1([a,b,c], X, L).
X = a,
L = [b, c] ;
X = b,
L = [a, c] ;
X = c,
L = [a, b] ;
false.
```

Comment: This is a good explanation of the principles behind why it occurs, but there's a much simpler fix for the provided code:

```prolog
elem_list_fix(Elems, X, ElemsNoX) :-
    append(ElemsAX, ElemsB, Elems),
    append(ElemsA, [X], ElemsAX),
    append(ElemsA, ElemsB, ElemsNoX).
```

By switching the order of evaluation, we can force bounds on the generated list. We know they must append to be the original, so that serves as an intuitive bound that prevents infinite recursion.